# How to remove rows based on the column values

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame, example:

```
> m <- matrix(c(3,6,2,5,3,3,2,5,4,3,5,3,6,3,6,7,5,8,2,5,5,4,9,2,2), nrow=5, ncol=5)
> colnames(m) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
> rownames(m) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
> m
  A B C D E
a 3 3 5 7 5
b 6 2 3 5 4
c 2 5 6 8 9
d 5 4 3 2 2
e 3 3 6 5 2
```

I would like to remove all rows, where A and/or B columns have greater value than C D and E columns.
So in this case rows b, d, e should be removed and I should get this:

```
  A B C D E
a 3 3 5 7 5
c 2 5 6 8 9
```

Can not remove them one by one because the data.frame has more than a million rows.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove them if the min of A,B is greater than the max of C,D,E?

Comment: I would advise to use `data.frame` instead of `matrix` object and the `subset` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subsetting, together with `pmin()` and `pmax()` to retain the values that you want. I'm not sure that I fully understand your criteria (you said "C D and E" but since you want to throw away row `e`, I think that you meant C, D *or* E ), but the following seems to do what you want:

```
> m[pmax(m[,"A"],m[,"B"])<=pmin(m[,"C"],m[,"D"],m[,"E"]),]
  A B C D E
a 3 3 5 7 5
c 2 5 6 8 9
```

Comment: Exactly, I want to remove the rows where the min values of A and/or B columns are greater than the max values of C,D and E columns. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# creating the df
m <- matrix(c(3,6,2,5,3,3,2,5,4,3,5,3,6,3,6,7,5,8,2,5,5,4,9,2,2), nrow=5, ncol=5)
colnames(m) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
rownames(m) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

# initialize as data frame. 
m <- as.data.frame(m)
df_n <- m
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  #print(i)
  #print(paste(max(m[,1:2][i,]), max(m[,3:5][i,])))
  if(max(m[,1:2][i,]) > (max(m[,3:4][i,])) || max(m[,1:2][i,]) > ((m[,5])[i])){
    #df_n <- m[-i,]
    df_n[i,] <- NA
  }
}
#df_n
df_n <- df_n[complete.cases(df_n), ]
print(df_n)

Results
> print(df_n)
  A B C D E
a 3 3 5 7 5
c 2 5 6 8 9
```

Comment: @loannis this played me around until i realised you wanted or meant C, D or E. Please correct your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with `apply`:

```
m[apply(m, 1, function(x) max(x[1], x[2]) < min(x[3], x[4], x[5])),]
```

**Result:**

```
  A B C D E
a 3 3 5 7 5
c 2 5 6 8 9
```

I think what you actually meant is to remove rows where *max(A, B) > min(C, D, E)*, which translates to keep rows where *all* values of A and B are smaller than *all* values of C, D, and E.